# Does Angular Universal integrate with local Express APIs?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, nestjs

Say I already have a REST API implemented with Nest and want to use the same Nest server instance to implement my Angular universal SSR--for calls to my `/api/foo` paths on that Nest server from the Angular app, do those calls go straight through to my Express handlers? Is this even a desirable outcome?

Comment: Why do you absolutely want to use the same server?

Comment: I don't have to absolutely use the same server, I guess there are two separate questions here:

1) Is it possible to turn HTTP calls into local method calls when Angular is in SSR mode?
2) Is it a good idea to have the Angular SSR server and REST API server run in the same process? (probably not)